# AS3 Change depth based on y position and stationary objects

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, sorting, depth

This is a little hard to describe.

I'm working on a game which simulates some depth of field by arranging objects based on their y position.

There is a static background stage, and characters which will spawn and despawn and move around.

These characters should be ordered properly when they are in front of each other.

I also need to be able to use conditional checks to determine whether a character should be behind or in front of certain static objects.

I've tried breaking the problem down to its bare bones by making a file separate from the game which illustrates my problem.

---

In this example, I have two movieclips on the stage, bgBox and fgBox, which are black and yellow respectively.

In my code, I am creating 4 more boxes, each at different y positions. 3 of them are intended to be layered neatly in between the bgBox and fgBox, while the fourth one, which is purple, is intended to be on top of everything else.

Here is what happens when I export this:
http://www.fileize.com/files/32d824d3/992/sorting_test.swf

Here is my code:

```
var boxList:Array = new Array();
var unsortedBoxList:Array = new Array();
var initialSort:Boolean = true;

var blue_box:Shape = new Shape();
var red_box:Shape = new Shape();
var green_box:Shape = new Shape();
var purple_box:Shape = new Shape();

blue_box.graphics.lineStyle(1);
blue_box.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF, 1);
blue_box.graphics.drawRect(200,150,100,100);
red_box.graphics.lineStyle(1);
red_box.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000, 1);
red_box.graphics.drawRect(220,170,100,100);
green_box.graphics.lineStyle(1);
green_box.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00, 1);
green_box.graphics.drawRect(240,190,100,100);
purple_box.graphics.lineStyle(1);
purple_box.graphics.beginFill(0xFF00FF, 1);
purple_box.graphics.drawRect(220,230,100,100);

trace("adding boxes----");
addChild(green_box);
trace("green: "+green_box.name);
boxList.push(green_box);
addChild(blue_box);
trace("blue: "+blue_box.name);
boxList.push(blue_box);
addChild(purple_box);
trace("purple: "+purple_box.name);
boxList.push(purple_box);
addChild(red_box);
trace("red: "+red_box.name);
boxList.push(red_box);
trace("-----------------");

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop, false, 0, true);

function loop(e:Event):void
{
    sortObjects();
}

function sortObjects():void {
    if(initialSort == true){
        setChildIndex(bgBox,0);
        setChildIndex(fgBox,1);

        trace("initial sort----"); 
        trace("   - bgBox index: "+getChildIndex(bgBox));
        trace("   - fgBox index: "+getChildIndex(fgBox));
        trace("----------------");

        initialSort = false;
    }

    boxList.sortOn(y, Array.NUMERIC);
    trace("----------");
    trace("boxList sorted: ");
    for each(var j:Shape in boxList){
        trace(j.name);
    }
    trace("-----");

    trace("   - bgBox index: "+getChildIndex(bgBox));
    for each(var i:Shape in boxList){
        if(i.y > 220){
            trace("y > 220; purple box"); //never triggers? the purple box should be on top of everything.
            setChildIndex(i,(getChildIndex(fgBox)+1));
        }
        else 
        {
            setChildIndex(i,getChildIndex(fgBox));
            //all other boxes should be arranged neatly inbetween the black and yellow boxes.
        }

        trace(i.name+" index: "+getChildIndex(i));
    }
    trace("   - fgBox index: "+getChildIndex(fgBox));
}
```

Here is what I get in output, which is very strange:

```
adding boxes----
green: instance5
blue: instance3
purple: instance6
red: instance4
-----------------
initial sort----
      - bgBox index: 0
      - fgBox index: 1
----------------
----------
boxList sorted: 
instance6
instance3
instance5
instance4
-----
      - bgBox index: 0
instance6 index: 1
instance3 index: 2
instance5 index: 3
instance4 index: 4
      - fgBox index: 5
----------
boxList sorted: 
instance5
instance3
instance6
instance4
-----
      - bgBox index: 0
instance5 index: 5
instance3 index: 4
instance6 index: 3
instance4 index: 2
      - fgBox index: 1
----------
boxList sorted: 
instance6
instance3
instance5
instance4
-----
      - bgBox index: 0
instance6 index: 1
instance3 index: 2
instance5 index: 3
instance4 index: 4
      - fgBox index: 5
```

As you can now see (thanks to an idea from user Marty Wallace) the objects are not being sorted correctly by their Y values.

Here is a link to the source file, in case this will help:
http://www.fileize.com/files/edc632f3/2e6/sorting_test.fla

---

**Can anybody explain to me why this is happening? Can anybody provide a solution to this problem?**

Thanks in advance. This has had me stumped for a few days now.

Answer (score 1):

You could give this a try for starters, just to get the layering based off `y` working right:

```
boxList.sortOn("y" Array.NUMERIC);

for each(var i:Shape in boxList)
{
    // Bring to front.
    i.parent && i.parent.addChild(i);
}
```

As for this:

> Also, the output: "boxList sorted: [object Shape],[object Shape],[object Shape],[object Shape]" is completely unhelpful.

You can create your own class with a `toString()` method. Whatever this method returns will be what you see in the above. For example, if you make this class:

```
class Test extends Shape
{
     public function toString():String
     {
         return name;
     }
}
```

Then you would get something a little more useful / representative:

```
var ar:Array = [];

for(var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    var test:Test = new Test();
    ar.push(test);
}

trace(ar); // instance1,instance2,instance3
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. I am now tracing the more useful names, and am getting some very odd traces. I will update my code and files and replace the old ones in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't push bgBox and fgBox into that array to get them properly sorted. And you've missed the correct sortOn argument - you're setting "y" without quotes, while it REQUIRES quotes there.